# Cygwin Bash Script?

Tags: cygwin, bash-scripting

I have no real clue about linux, but need a simple script to copy what I manually do
1. Open Cygwin
2. Type a directory name (micros)
3. Type a command (reload)

That's it...I just can't get it to work.  anyone have a

Comment: What have you scriptedso far? Besides, you do not need to know anything linx specific using cygwin. Knowledge of Bash would be sufficient.

Comment: http://www.tldp.org/guides.html - has two "bash" oriented guides, reading & understanding these will have you do work that will impress anyone.

Answer (score 1):

Given you have cygwin installed in c:\cygwin you can do something link this

```
c:\cygwin\bin\bash.exe --login -i -c 'cd "/cygdrive/c/pathtofolder"; reload'
```

A quick search on this forum points you to [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/115587/how-do-i-create-a-shortcut-that-opens-cygwin-bash-shell-on-a-directory-of-my-cho) where [John T](https://superuser.com/users/1931/john-t) give this same answer. Credit goes to him.

Hope it helps